# In which cases prior to the Greek crisis did the IMF admit mistakes in it's economic policies?

Tags: international-economics, financial-crises

Has the IMF ever admitted mistakes on it's economic policies prior to the Greek crisis?

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with economics? This seems like more of a history question.

Comment: @denesp: It has to do with the history of economics. It is more likely that someone gives a relevant answer here, than in the history SE. Maybe I am wrong, but since I hang a lot in the history SE, I know more or less the profiles of people answering there.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about history, not economics

Comment: @EnergyNumbers It is about history related to economics. I got my answer, so if you think it is wise to close it, do so. The profile of people answering here is more suitable, than those who answer in the history site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

> The International Monetary Fund yesterday admitted that its mistakes
>   helped plunge Argentina deeper into the red during the currency crisis
>   that crippled the country's economy three years ago.
>
> In a report published yesterday by its independent evaluation office,
>   the IMF said it ought to have prevented the Argentine government from
>   following poor economic policies.
>
> "IMF surveillance failed to highlight the growing vulnerabilities in
>   the authorities' choice of policies and the IMF erred by supporting
>   inadequate policies too long," it said.

[IMF admits mistakes in Argentina crisis](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/finance/2891368/IMF-admits-mistakes-in-Argentina-crisis.html) By Edmund Conway

The actual report is here: [IMF's Independent Evaluation Office Announces Release of Report on the Role of the IMF in Argentina](https://www.imf.org/External/NP/ieo/2004/pr/eng/pr0402.htm)